# Changing UICollectionView cell image at regular interval

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an IOS 10.x application using UICollectionView and would like to change the image of specific cells, at regular interval.

The code below shows the current implementation. Even though it should change  the cell background image every half of second, it changes the images immediately disregarding the NSThread SleepAt interval of 0.5 seconds.

I suspect something about the main thread handling or the ReloadItem method but hasn't reached a clear conclusion. Any insight is very welcome! Thank you.

```
NSNumber* originalCardSelected;
int position;

for (int i = 0; i < [opponentOriginalCardArray count]; i++) {

  originalCardSelected = [opponentOriginalCardArray objectAtIndex:i];
  position = [self convertLevelDataPositionToCellViewPosition:[originalCardSelected intValue]];

  NSMutableArray *tmpBackgroundAssets = [self getNewAssetBackgroundBasedOnBackgroundType:playbackBackground Index:position];
    self.backgroundAssets = tmpBackgroundAssets;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



        [collectionViewRoot reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[collectionViewRoot indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
    });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];


}
```

Comment: I think that `UIImageView` `animationImages` property may be more suitable for what you are trying to do.

Comment: dispatch_async executes the code asynchronously which is why your reload is happening before the line   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5].

Comment: Better use `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) methods and add your for loop inside it.

**Remember** to not keep strong references inside the block to avoid retain cycles.

**EDIT:**

and in the completion block, you can check if finished and add your NSThread methods